# How to set up JSON based tree with node and parent data values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following HTML:

```
<section class="tree"></section>
```

Relatively simple... Now, I have the following JSON object:

```
var input = {
    label: 'Earth',
    type: 'planet',
    children: [{
        label: 'Australia',
        type: 'country',
        children: [{
            label: 'Sydney',
            type: 'city',
            children: [{
                label: 'Office One',
                type: 'office',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        label: 'USA',
        type: 'country',
        children: [{
            label: 'Phoenix',
            type: 'city',
            children: [{
                label: 'Office Two',
                type: 'office',
                children: []
            }]
        }, {
            label: 'New York',
            type: 'city',
            children: [{
                label: 'Office Three',
                type: 'office',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

I'm trying to create a simple list of DIVs with a node number (which increases with each new node we come across), as well as its parent node.

So far, I've managed to get the node worked out... but the parent always seems to refer back to the value of the node minus one instead of the node of the respective parent...

As a result my list is looking like this:

```
<section class="tree">
  <div class="node lvl0" node="1" parent="0">Earth</div>
  <div class="node lvl1" node="2" parent="1">Australia</div>
  <div class="node lvl2" node="3" parent="2">Sydney</div>
  <div class="node lvl3" node="4" parent="3">Office One</div>
  <div class="node lvl1" node="5" parent="4">USA</div>
  <div class="node lvl2" node="6" parent="5">Phoenix</div>
  <div class="node lvl3" node="7" parent="6">Office Two</div>
  <div class="node lvl2" node="8" parent="7">New York</div>
  <div class="node lvl3" node="9" parent="8">Office Three</div>
</section>
```

instead of this:

```
<section class="tree">
  <div class="node lvl0" node="1" parent="0">Earth</div>
  <div class="node lvl1" node="2" parent="1">Australia</div>
  <div class="node lvl2" node="3" parent="2">Sydney</div>
  <div class="node lvl3" node="4" parent="3">Office One</div>
  <div class="node lvl1" node="5" parent="1">USA</div>
  <div class="node lvl2" node="6" parent="5">Phoenix</div>
  <div class="node lvl3" node="7" parent="6">Office Two</div>
  <div class="node lvl2" node="8" parent="5">New York</div>
  <div class="node lvl3" node="9" parent="8">Office Three</div>
</section>
```

This is my code:

```
nodeCnt = 0;
var dispTree = function(tree,lvl=0,idx=0,prt=0) {
idx++;
$(".tree").append("<div class='node lvl"+lvl+"' node='"+(++nodeCnt)+"' parent='"+prt+"'>"+tree.label+"</div>");
parent = nodeCnt;
for (var i = 0; i < tree.children.length; i++){


         dispTree(tree.children[i], lvl+1, idx, parent);
    }
};

dispTree(input)
```

Can someone please tell me what I may be doing wrong with this code, and how to correct it?

I have it on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eliseo_d/cn3s7apz/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion like this.

```js
var input = {"label":"Earth","type":"planet","children":[{"label":"Australia","type":"country","children":[{"label":"Sydney","type":"city","children":[{"label":"Office One","type":"office","children":[]}]}]},{"label":"USA","type":"country","children":[{"label":"Phoenix","type":"city","children":[{"label":"Office Two","type":"office","children":[]}]},{"label":"New York","type":"city","children":[{"label":"Office Three","type":"office","children":[]}]}]}]}


let node = 1;
var result = []

function tree(lvl, parent = 0, node, data) {
  let div = `<div class="node lvl${lvl}" node="${node}" parent="${parent==0 ? 0 : parent - 1}">${data.label}</div>`;
  n = node += 1
  if (data.children.length) {
    data.children.forEach(e => tree(lvl + 1, node, n, e))
  }

  result.push($(div))
}

tree(0, 0, node, input)

$('body').append(...result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```